# django - Multiple uploads to later edit as multiple posts

Tags: django, post, mp3

I'm new to django and I'm doing a music project.

I want to select multiple mp3 and upload it  and then the form appears to me to edit the parameters for each mp3 separately (example, artist, title, image, etc).

upload multiple files in one input, to edit later for separate post.

Thx

Comment: You can use `ManyToMany` field.

Comment: Please tell us more about your current project: at least the model you built, maybe the form you intend to display and related view